# run a macro on dial cmd Asterisk 18

Tags: macros, asterisk

i want run a macro on dial cmd,

this is my macro `

```
[macro-subrao]
exten => s,1,AMD()
exten => s,n,Set(RAO=${AMDSTATUS})
```

`

this is my dialplan
`

```
 exten => _+33.,n,Set(FILENAME=${EXTEN}_${SIPCALLID})
 exten => _+33.,n,Monitor(wav,${FILENAME},b)
 exten => _+33.,n,Dial(${SIPTrunk}/${EXTEN},,M(subrao))
```

`

i get this error

```
[Dec  6 08:03:40] WARNING[27509][C-00000001]: app.c:297 ast_app_exec_macro: Cannot run 'Macro(subrao)'.  The application is not available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asterisk above version 13 app_macro is depricated. You have build it manually if you need it using "make menuconfig" while compiling.

You can replace it by gosub application.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Dial

All samples was rewrited for use gosub.